# Redirect to a default page when server throws http error 403

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

We have multiple applications pointing to the same physical directory. On one of the sites, I would like to configure custom error redirects for http error code 403. when I make a change in the web.config file, the changes are all applied to all the applications. Is there a way to limit the change to just one application. I know about location Element by specifying the path but not entirely sure on how to use it. Can someone tell me if this is the correct approach or if there is an approach other than using location element in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

> You can create separate web.config file for each application and than
>   add settings as you want this will not effect other applications.You can override configurations and add new for a specific application.